# Simple SVM algorithm to predict an integer

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

In my project, we are supposed to use an SVM based algorithm. So to get a basic idea about implementation of SVM, we are trying to implement an algorithm, which when fed with an array of 1000 integers where first 95 integers are of values ranging from 0-5, then the next 5 around 10,000 and then again 95 integers of values ranging from 0-5 and next 5 around 10,000 and so on, will be able to predict the next 100 integers (1001st - 1100th) with first 95 integers around 0-5 and the last 5 around 10,000 ...

How to implement it? Preferred programming language is python. So are there any svm modules like libsvm which will facilitate this?

I know this might be a stupid question, but any help would be appreciated a lot !!

Please reply

Answer (score 1):

Here are some resources on AI (SVM specifically) from the [Python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonForArtificialIntelligence):

> [Milk](http://packages.python.org/milk/) - Milk is a machine learning toolkit in Python. Its focus is on supervised classification with several classifiers available: SVMs (based on libsvm), k-NN, random forests, decision trees. It also performs feature selection. These classifiers can be combined in many ways to form different classification systems.
>
> [LibSVM](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/libsvm/) - LIBSVM is an integrated software for support vector classification, (C-SVC, nu-SVC), regression (epsilon-SVR, nu-SVR) and distribution estimation (one-class SVM). It supports multi-class classification. A Python interface is available by by default.
>
> [Shogun](http://www.shogun-toolbox.org/) - The machine learning toolbox's focus is on large scale kernel methods and especially on Support Vector Machines (SVM) . It provides a generic SVM object interfacing to several different SVM implementations, among them the state of the art OCAS, Liblinear, LibSVM, SVMLight, SVMLin and GPDT. Each of the SVMs can be combined with a variety of kernels. The toolbox not only provides efficient implementations of the most common kernels, like the Linear, Polynomial, Gaussian and Sigmoid Kernel but also comes with a number of recent string kernels. SHOGUN is implemented in C++ and interfaces to Matlab(tm), R, Octave and Python and is proudly released as Machine Learning Open Source Software

Comment: Thank you :) :) Currently downloading LibSVM. And another thing, the problem which I mentioned earlier, predicting the next 100 integers based on previous data, this is solvable using LibSVM (SVM) , right ? I am particularly novice at this field, so please reply :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with SVM from [SciKit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html). Other options include [svmlight](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/svmlight) and [LaSVM](http://leon.bottou.org/projects/lasvm).